# How to find formula that generates binary sequence?

Tags: php, formula

I have a loop of objects that must have the following appearance:

> 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...

I need to make a statement that decides which output (0 or 1) should appear for each object in sequence. What is the best way to do it?
Is there any method for "*reverse engineering to formulas*"?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean with "loop of object"? How do the sequences appear? What do the object look like? What do you mean with "style" of object in sequence? Answer these questions, followed with an example of what you tried, and we might get somewhere. Finally, you can reverse engineer about anything if A -> B but A !-> C (C being anything else) and you know what A is for each B.

Comment: Actually this bad question could be a good question. I'm pretty interested how should one build algorithm that can mimic input data in other way than repeating them.

Comment: What is the expected output? and what does the input look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well umm... there could be ALL SORTS of solutions to this. Here's an example:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    echo ($i % 4 <= 1 ? 1 : 0) . ' ';
}
```

Output: `1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0`

Explanation: divide the number by 4. If the remainder is 0 or 1, then you get a 1, otherwise you get a 0.

For reverse-engineering, it's really a matter of trial and error, or pattern recognition. You could also try Wolfram which has sequence solving: http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Sequences.html